# How to add images into Flowlayoutpanel when item is selected in Combobox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, combobox, flowlayoutpanel

How to add icons with a button (for devices in a house) when selected in a `ComboBox` into a `FlowLayoutPanel`.  The `ComboBox` has a list of different devices and when you select one, the power rating appears in a `TextBox`.

Is it possible to store this information and an icon in a `FlowLayoutPanel`?

However, I am not sure if a `FlowLayoutPanel` is the correct option to do this.

Comment: Winforms, ASP.NET, WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to store this information and an icon in a flow layoutpanel?

Not really, since the panel is meant to store UI controls, not arbitrary data. You *can* of course work around this.

One way to do this is with a backing list of custom objects that contain an Image. The code below defines such a class (with a title and image for each item) and uses this info plus a couple of event hooks to fill the panel with images based on the combobox, and then set the text in a textbox based on clicks on the images.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();



    public Context c = new Context();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        itemList.Add(new Item("First"));
        itemList.Add(new Item("Second"));
        itemList.Add(new Item("Third" ));
        comboBox1.DataSource = itemList;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Title";

        foreach (var itemView in itemList)
        {
            itemView.onClick += this.ItemClicked;
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = (ComboBox) sender;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(itemList[s.SelectedIndex].ThisImage);
    }

    private void ItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Item v = (Item)sender;
        AssignTextBox(v.Title);
    }

    public void AssignTextBox(string text)
    {
        textBox1.Text = text;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public PictureBox ThisImage { get; set; }

    public delegate void clicked(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event clicked onClick;

    public Item(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
        ThisImage = new PictureBox();
        ThisImage.Paint += Paint_This;
        ThisImage.Click += onClicked;
    }

    public void onClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (onClick != null)
            onClick(this, e);
    }

    private void Paint_This(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Font f = new Font("Verdana", 14))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Title, f, Brushes.Black, new Point(1,1));
        }
    }

}
```